# Relation between the eigendecomposition of an operator in a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ and the Cartan subalgebra

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-algebras

I am trying to understand the relation between eigendecompositions of elements of Lie algebras and a Cartan subalgebra of that group.

- Consider an element $\Omega \in \mathfrak{g}$, $\dim{\mathfrak{g}} = M$
  where $\mathfrak{g}\subseteq \mathfrak{su}(N)$.
- Let $G$ be the Lie group generated by $\mathfrak{g}$. Then I know that there exists a $g\in G$ such that $g \Omega g^{-1} = h\in\mathfrak{h}$, where $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.
- The matrix $h$ can be represented by a diagonal matrix since a Cartan subalgebra is maximally abelian. All Cartan subalgebras are identical up to conjugation.

I know that there exists a $u\in \mathrm{SU}(N)$ such that $u \Omega u^\dagger= d$, where $d$ contains the eigenvalues of $\Omega$. I see that $d$ is an element of a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$, but is $d$ also in a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: There is no "the" Cartan subalgebra of a Lie algebra. Most Lie algebras have infinitely many CSAs. Beyond that you have not defined what $\mathfrak h$ is. Also, are you sure $\mathfrak g$ can be *any* subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$, for example, any one-dimensional subspace? Also, what is your actual question, and are the bullet points things you wonder about, or take for granted, or something else?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to define $\mathfrak{h}$, that should be the CSA of $\mathfrak{g}$. Also I only consider $\dim{\mathfrak{g}}>1$.

Comment: My question is: Is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $\Omega\in\mathfrak{g}$ an element of the CSA $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: As I said "the" CSA of $\mathfrak g$ is not well-defined. And I think I suggested counterexamples to that question.

Comment: I edited my question to refer to "a" CSA of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: I see that this does not hold for a one-dimensional subspace.

Comment: But then my next question would be, for which $\mathfrak{g}$ does this hold?

Comment: Well an obvious necessary criterion is that $\mathfrak g$ contains nonzero diagonal matrices at all. I don't know if that is sufficient (I doubt it).